# Contact form not submitting using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm building a contact form for my site using `jQuery validation plugin`, ajax call to forward the data to the PHP file, and finally sending the email. Seems like the data is not passed to the **php mailer**. I'm new to server side technologies, I read a lot but still can't make this working, so please advise me.

the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your name" type="text" value="" required>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
   <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="your@email.com" type="email" value="" required>   
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputMessage">Message</label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
   <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Message" rows="3"  required></textarea>
   <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

the javascript:

```
/*validate contact form */
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            inputName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            inputEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            inputMessage: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "name required",
                minlength: "name must be at least 2 characters"
            },
            email: {
                required: "email required"
            },
            message: {
                required: "message required",
                minlength: 10
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('form').ajaxSubmit({

                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"index2.php",
                success: function() {

                    alert("message sent");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("due to an error msg wasnt sent");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

php file:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $name = trim($_POST['inputName']);
    $email = trim($_POST['inputEmail']);
    $message = $_POST['inputMessage'];
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form';
    $to = 'example@example.com';
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` isn't set when you use AJAX.

Comment: have you check ajax called or not ?

Comment: There is enough information about AJAX forms/calls on SO. I've posted two complete answers about this already, so have others.

Comment: @JasonK Flag it as a duplicate if you know of a previous answer that's apropos.

Comment: I think form is submit instead ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use checking if:

```
  if (isset($_POST['inputName'])){
//rest part here
}
```

// and see if the file is in `same directory` otherwise give relative path.

use this to send form content:

```
submitHandler: function() {
    $('form').ajaxSubmit({

        type:"POST",
        data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
        url:"submit.php",
        success: function() {

            alert("message sent");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("due to an error msg wasnt sent");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The php and html files are located at the root folder, the js file is located inside "includes/js/file.js". That might be one of the issues?

Comment: see in console whether the file is loaded or not.

Comment: It seems I had a problem with one of my jquery files, edited the path, it sends the mail, but all fields are empty.

Comment: remove form from this:submitHandler: function(form) { and use data:$('#contactForm').serialize(),

Comment: it works now, eventually the only thing i changed was  $('form').ajaxSubmit({ TO->  $('#contactForm').ajaxSubmit({. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`$(form).serialize()` doesn't include the `submit` field (how would it know which submit button you clicked on?), so `if ($_POST['submit'])` will never succeed. Use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
```

instead.

Or, if this script is only used for AJAX calls, and not loaded directly by the browser, you can omit that check entirely, as in Glizzweb's answer.

Comment: form not submitting using ajax instead form getting refresh. I think this is the main problem. rest can be figure out after that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had a problem with the path of one of my jquery files. In addition, I tried what you and Glizzweb suggested, I'm able to receive a mail but all fields are empty. What could cause that?

Comment: Your `$from` is wrong. It should be `$from = 'From: Demo Contact Form <you@yourdomain.com>';`

Comment: it works now, eventually the only thing i changed was $('form').ajaxSubmit TO-> $('#contactForm').ajaxSubmit. Thanks! But could you please elaborate about the wrong usage of the $_POST['submit']? I didnt quite get it.

Comment: A form can have multiple submit buttons. When you submit a form the traditional way, the browser includes the submit button that you clicked on as a parameter. But when you use `(form).serialize()`, it just gets all the normal form fields. It's not triggered by a specific submit button, so it doesn't add that parameter to the serialized string.

Comment: and `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` means that if the server received a post request, doesnt matter the way it was sent, then do whats inside the brackets?

Comment: Right. That will be set if the POST came from AJAX or from normal form submission, as long as they specify the `POST` method.

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax.php remove `$_POST["submit"]`

```
<?php
    $name = trim($_POST['inputName']);
    $email = trim($_POST['inputEmail']);
    $message = $_POST['inputMessage'];
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form';
    $to = 'example@example.com';
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In ajax page $_POST['submit'] need remove because you post values using "$(form).serialize()" and In you not post value to ajax page. remove if condition "if ($_POST["submit"]) {}" and change like this "if (!empty($_POST["inputName"])) { }"

```
 $name = trim($_POST['inputName']);
$email = trim($_POST['inputEmail']);
.....
....
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/additional-methods.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            inputName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            inputEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            inputMessage: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "name value required",
                minlength: "name must be at least 2 characters"
            },
            email: {
                required: "email is required"
            },
            message: {
                required: "message is required",
                minlength: 10
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert($('form').html());
            $.ajax({

                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"test1.php",
                success: function() {

                    alert("message sent");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("due to an error msg wasnt sent");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your name" type="text" value="" >
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
   <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="your@email.com" type="email" value="" >   
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputMessage">Message</label>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
   <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Message" rows="3"  ></textarea>
   <input class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working and showing message sent and ajax call also made. you are doing some mistakes while performing ajax call. as jquery validation plugin does not provide any ajaxsubmit function instead use jquery ajax function as i have used. try it and let me know for further issue.

Change this code to fit your requirement.